# how to get only child name not with parent name in many2many field with many2many_tags widget odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have the Customer field in the Sale Order form.
I have added a new Many2many field with many2many_tags for Child Contacts of Customers in the Sale order form.
Now when I change Customer this new field fills with its child contacts.
But it comes with a Customer name.
I want to display only the name of child contacts.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are coming from js file of many2many_tags
In this it shows values of display_name.
You can change the code as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit the name_get method like below.

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    if not self._context.get('ADD_CONTEXT_ON_SALEORDER_ACTION_AND_ALSO_ON_FIELD'):
        return super(ResPartner, self).name_get()
    res = []
    for partner in self:
        res.append((partner.id, partner.name))
    return res
```

as per above code you also you need to add context in sale order action and on that many2many field too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother but still it's coming with a parent contact name.